# Perlin Noise terrain in Unity3D

Tags: c#, algorithm, object-oriented, random, unity3d

I've recently had time to devise another program so this time I decided to write the Perlin Noise algorithm in code. I have succeeded and the code works but I can't help but feel that my practices while writing are still not as good as they should be (especially since I'm still pretty new to the topic of programming). **Please note** that as I am working in Unity I have not separated the class files that I wrote into different source files. The code is comprised of a total of 3 class files: the main *MonoBehaviour class* named *perlin_terrain* and the two I have declared - named "*Grid*" and "*Point*".

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class perlin_terrain : MonoBehaviour {

    public Terrain terrain;

    public int gridResolution = 512; // Will be adjusted to be divisible by the subdivision value. 
    public int gridSubdivision = 4;  // Value must be a power of 2.

    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float steepness = 0.12f;

    Grid grid;

    private static float[,] heights;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if (gridResolution < terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution)
            throw new ArgumentException("Given resolution must be equal to or exceed terrain heightmap resolution.");

        grid = new Grid(gridResolution, gridSubdivision);
        grid.SteepnessCoefficient = steepness;

        heights = new float[terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution, terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution];

        determineTerrain();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    void determineTerrain()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution; x++)
            {
                heights[y, x] = grid.getAmplitude(x, y);
            }

        terrain.terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, heights);
    }
}

public class Grid
{
    public float steepnessCoefficient = 0.12f; // The closer it is to one, the steeper the terrain. Has to be greater than or equal to zero.

    private static int resolution;
    private static int subdivision;
    private int subdivisionInterval;

    private Point[] points;

    public Grid(int _resolution, int _subdivision)
    {
        if (Mathf.Log(_subdivision, 2) % 1 != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Subdivision value MUST be a power of 2.");

        while (_resolution % _subdivision != 0)
        {
            _resolution++;
        }

        resolution = _resolution;
        subdivision = _subdivision;
        subdivisionInterval = resolution / subdivision;

        points = new Point[(int)Mathf.Pow(subdivision + 1, 2)];

        generatePoints();
    }

    private void generatePoints()
    {
        int n = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= subdivision; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= subdivision; j++)
            {
                points[n] = new Point(j * subdivisionInterval, i * subdivisionInterval);
                n++;
            }
    }

    public float getAmplitude(int x, int y)
    {
        float pointX = ((float)x / (float)subdivisionInterval) % 1f , pointY = ((float)y / (float)subdivisionInterval) % 1f;

        Vector2[] distanceVectors = { new Vector2(pointX, pointY), new Vector2(pointX - 1, pointY), new Vector2(pointX, pointY - 1), new Vector2(pointX - 1, pointY - 1) };

        float value1 = 0, value2 = 0, value3 = 0, value4 = 0;
        float weighed1 = 0, weighed2 = 0;
        float amplitude = 0;

        List<Point> unitPoints = new List<Point>();

        unitPoints = getUnitPoints(x, y);

        int n = 0;

        foreach (Point point in unitPoints)
        {
            switch (n)
            {
                case 0:
                    value1 = Vector2.Dot(point.GradientVector, distanceVectors[0]);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value2 = Vector2.Dot(point.GradientVector, distanceVectors[1]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    value3 = Vector2.Dot(point.GradientVector, distanceVectors[2]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    value4 = Vector2.Dot(point.GradientVector, distanceVectors[3]);
                    break;
            }

            n++;
        }

        weighed1 = Mathf.Lerp(value1, value2, fadeValue(pointX));
        weighed2 = Mathf.Lerp(value3, value4, fadeValue(pointX));

        amplitude = Mathf.Lerp(weighed1, weighed2, fadeValue(pointY));

        return ((amplitude + 1) / 2) * steepnessCoefficient; // Normalize amplitude to range from 0 to 1. (and apply steepness coefficient)
    }

    private float fadeValue(float value)
    {
        return 6 * Mathf.Pow(value, 5) - 15 * Mathf.Pow(value, 4) + 10 * Mathf.Pow(value, 3);
    }

    private List<Point> getUnitPoints(int x, int y)
    {
        int unitNumberX = (int)(x / subdivisionInterval), unitNumberY = (int)(y / subdivisionInterval);
        List<Point> unitPoints = new List<Point>();

        foreach (Point point in points)
        {
            if (point.X == unitNumberX * subdivisionInterval && point.Y == unitNumberY * subdivisionInterval)
            {
                unitPoints.Add(point);
            }
            else if (point.X == unitNumberX * subdivisionInterval + subdivisionInterval && point.Y == unitNumberY * subdivisionInterval)
            {
                unitPoints.Add(point);
            }
            else if (point.X == unitNumberX * subdivisionInterval && point.Y == unitNumberY * subdivisionInterval + subdivisionInterval)
            {
                unitPoints.Add(point);
            }
            else if (point.X == unitNumberX * subdivisionInterval + subdivisionInterval && point.Y == unitNumberY * subdivisionInterval + subdivisionInterval)
            {
                unitPoints.Add(point);
            }
        }

        return unitPoints;
    }

    //------------------------------ Property declarations ------------------------------

    public static int Resolution
    {
        get { return resolution; }
    }

    public static int Subdivision
    {
        get { return subdivision; }
    }

    public float SteepnessCoefficient
    {
        get { return steepnessCoefficient; }
        set { steepnessCoefficient = value; }
    }
}

public class Point
{
    private static Vector2[] vectors = { new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(-1, 1), new Vector2(1, -1), new Vector2(-1, -1) };
    private Vector2 gradientVector;

    private int x, y;

    public Point(int _x, int _y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;

        gradientVector = vectors[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 4)];
    }

    //------------------------------ Property declarations ------------------------------

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
    }

    public Vector2 GradientVector
    {
        get { return gradientVector; }
    }
}
```

I have some work to do at the moment but I'll be back in a few hours to see you guys' awesome and much appreciated feedback. :)

Comment: So every time you construct an instance of `Grid` you want the `static` variables `resolution` and `subdivision` to be set? Seems odd. Doesn't seem like they need to be static at all. Maybe `gridSubdivision` in the `perlin_terrain` class but in the `Grid` class it doesn't seem like they need to be static. Is there some reason you have them static?

Comment: Also, are you aware you could do `public int X { get; private set; }` instead of a getter only and a backing field for your `Point` class? I do recall something to do with fields and the inspector in Unity but I thought the fields had to be public not private so I'm not sure.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why I decided to set them as 'static' now that I'm reviewing the code. I think at the time I did it because I was using the two values to initialize an array, but I ultimately decided to use the 'terrainData' resolution property to initialize it and I seem to have forgotten to delete the static keyword from the two fields. Oh well, what can ya' do... :D I also see now that I probably should have made 'Point' a 'struct' instead of a 'class' but it's whatever... As for the property declarations I'm not exactly sure. Could you maybe elaborate? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've re-written your point class to be a bit more concise and to-the-*point* (hehe).

```
public class Point
{
    private static Vector2[] vectors = {
        new Vector2(1, 1),
        new Vector2(-1, 1),
        new Vector2(1, -1),
        new Vector2(-1, -1)
    };

    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }
    public Vector2 GradientVector { get; private set; }

    public Point (int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        gradientVector = vectors[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,vectors.length)];
    }
}
```

The following was done,

- **Properties** I made use of private setters with public getters condensing your two variables/members into a single one. Only the code inside the class can set the values of `X`, `Y`, and `GradientVector` but anyone can view it.
- **Magic Numbers** Your `UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,4)` was okay but if you ever add/remove vectors (for whatever reason) form the `vectors` variable then you might forget to update the constructor. Using `vectors.length` removes the possibility for that entirely.
- **Lines of Code** Additionally instead of the initial 32 lines of code it is now 20 lines of code including the fact that I make vectors take 6 lines instead of 1 line to improve readability.

**Reduce & Cache Calculations**

```
private List<Point> getUnitPoints(int x, int y)
{
    int unitNumberX = (int)(x / subdivisionInterval) * subdivisionInterval;
    int unitNumberY = (int)(y / subdivisionInterval) * subdivisionInterval;
    List<Point> unitPoints = new List<Point>();

    foreach (Point point in points)
    {
        var isCompatibleX = point.X == unitNumberX 
                         || point.X == unitNumberX + subdivisionInterval;

        var isCompatibleY = point.Y == unitNumberY 
                         || point.Y == unitNumberY + subdivisionInterval;

        if (isCompatibleX && isCompatibleY)
        {
            unitPoints.Add(point);
        }
    }

    return unitPoints;
}
```

Things I noticed with your `getUnitPoints(..)` function.

- **Reduce** `unitNumberX` and `unitNumberY` can include the multiplication with `subdivisionInterval`. They're not used separately anywhere else in the function. This reduces the number of times you have to calculate it.
- **Simplify** Your `if-elseif` chain consisted of 4 conditions in which they all resulted in the same action. This should be able to be simplified to the above (don't just take the word of a stranger on the internet though double-check that it works the same as yours before; both solutions that *should* work and *shouldn't*).

**Arrays & More Reduction**

```
public float getAmplitude(int x, int y)
{
    float sub = (float)subdivisionInterval; // example
    float pointX = ((float)x / sub) % 1f;
    float pointY = ((float)y / sub) % 1f;

    Vector2[] distanceVectors = { new Vector2(pointX, pointY), new Vector2(pointX - 1, pointY), new Vector2(pointX, pointY - 1), new Vector2(pointX - 1, pointY - 1) };

    float amplitude = 0;
    float weighed1 = 0, weighed2 = 0;

    List<Point> unitPoints = getUnitPoints(x, y);
    float[] values = new float[unitPoints.length];

    for (int n = 0; n < unitPoints.length && n < values.length; n++)
    {   
        values[n] = Vector2.Dot(unitPoints[n].GradientVector, distanceVectors[n]);
    }

    weighed1 = Mathf.Lerp(value1, value2, fadeValue(pointX));
    weighed2 = Mathf.Lerp(value3, value4, fadeValue(pointX));

    amplitude = Mathf.Lerp(weighed1, weighed2, fadeValue(pointY));

    return ((amplitude + 1) / 2) * steepnessCoefficient; // Normalize amplitude to range from 0 to 1. (and apply steepness coefficient)
}
```

- **Arrays** When you see something like `value1, value2, etc` it's a huge indicator an array might be better. If you switch your 4 value variables into an array it opens a door. Suddenly your switch statement no longer needs to be a switch statement because `value1, value2, etc` can become `values[n]` and from there you can reduce your switch statement into a single line.
- **Loops** `foreach` loops are for when you *don't* need an index. `for` loops are for when you *need* an index. You're using a foreach then keeping your own index, that can be reduced to a single for loop.
- **Calculations vs Memory** Generally speaking games require quick performance. The tradeoff of quick performance is usually memory (aka another variable). You might consider caching calculations/casts/etc that you use more than once. This is an extreme example and probably unnecessary (but for the sake of example) you could make a float variable and store `subdivisionInterval` casted as a float so you don't need to cast it a second time (i.e. `pointX` and `pointY`). Again, a cast probably doesn't need cached as it's nearly negligible but it can be helpful to keep this concept in mind.

**Final words**

I noticed you have a `Point[]` for your grid. One thing you could do is make it a jagged array (i.e. `Point[][]` an array of arrays) this way you can make each point at its coordinate position (i.e. Point[x][y]) for quick and simplistic access conceptually.

That said you have a working solution so unless you're having trouble conceptually keeping track of your current solution I wouldn't change it.

I hope that you find this helpful.

Comment: Thoroughly explained and well written. Thank you so much for the helpful tips. I wish you a very nice day. Gladly accepting your answer. :)

Comment: By the way the part where you store the booleans in a variable is sooo clever. I haven't really thought about that before to shorten checks.... Very helpful tip. :)